# list of matrices to ragged array

Tags: arrays, r, list, matrix

How can I convert a list of matrices of various dimensions into a ragged array?

Here's a list of matrices (in my actual use-case they all are 2 cols by a variable number of rows):

```
set.seed(007)
my_list<- lapply(1:10, function(i) matrix(data = runif(sample(seq(2,10,2), 1)), ncol = 2))
```

Which looks like this:

```
my_list
[[1]]
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.39774545 0.3400624
[2,] 0.11569778 0.9720625
[3,] 0.06974868 0.1658555
[4,] 0.24374939 0.4591037
[5,] 0.79201043 0.1717481

[[2]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] 0.77281195 0.45344777
[2,] 0.09630154 0.08470071

[[3]]
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.0087046 0.6394489
[2,] 0.9857371 0.2952232
[3,] 0.3165848 0.9967037

[[4]]
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.98873914 0.3622208
[2,] 0.06564574 0.6799935
[3,] 0.62703876 0.2637199
[4,] 0.49047504 0.1857143
[5,] 0.97102441 0.1851432

[[5]]
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.8470244 0.7905856
[2,] 0.4980761 0.8384639

[[6]]
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.7994758 0.4367756
[2,] 0.3819431 0.9042177
[3,] 0.7597012 0.3195349

[[7]]
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.8162891 0.8984762

[[8]]
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.5730689 0.3868313
[2,] 0.7200795 0.1627908
[3,] 0.7740586 0.1872283
[4,] 0.6277608 0.3912495
[5,] 0.7229893 0.2739012

[[9]]
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.5043918 0.7638404

[[10]]
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.5440542 0.3370636
[2,] 0.6590872 0.4245263
[3,] 0.4687284 0.2870151
[4,] 0.4818055 0.6011915
```

And I want to get it to look like:

```
my_array
, , 1
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.39774545 0.3400624
[2,] 0.11569778 0.9720625
[3,] 0.06974868 0.1658555
[4,] 0.24374939 0.4591037
[5,] 0.79201043 0.1717481

, , 2
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] 0.77281195 0.45344777
[2,] 0.09630154 0.08470071

, , 3
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.0087046 0.6394489
[2,] 0.9857371 0.2952232
[3,] 0.3165848 0.9967037

, , 4
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.98873914 0.3622208
[2,] 0.06564574 0.6799935
[3,] 0.62703876 0.2637199
[4,] 0.49047504 0.1857143
[5,] 0.97102441 0.1851432

, , 5
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.8470244 0.7905856
[2,] 0.4980761 0.8384639

, , 6
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.7994758 0.4367756
[2,] 0.3819431 0.9042177
[3,] 0.7597012 0.3195349

, , 7
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.8162891 0.8984762

, , 8
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.5730689 0.3868313
[2,] 0.7200795 0.1627908
[3,] 0.7740586 0.1872283
[4,] 0.6277608 0.3912495
[5,] 0.7229893 0.2739012

, , 9
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.5043918 0.7638404

, , 10
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.5440542 0.3370636
[2,] 0.6590872 0.4245263
[3,] 0.4687284 0.2870151
[4,] 0.4818055 0.6011915
```

The obvious methods such as `simplify2array` and `abind` only seem to work when the matrices all have identical dimensions, so I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: R does not have a ragged array class. You will need to keep in list format and work around the difficulties, or accept having NA values in the "extra rows"

Comment: That explains it then. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as such?

Comment: It is worthy to know that if the list have matrices of the same dimension, then `abind` function from abind package will be very helpful. If `my_list` consists of matrices of equal dimension, then you can coerce it to be an array by executing `abind(my_list, along=0)` ;) e.g. `abind(list(matrix(1:4,2), matrix(1:4,2)), along=0)`. Another alternative could be using the base function `simplify2array` as in `simplify2array(list(matrix(1:4,2), matrix(1:4,2)))` :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R does not have a ragged array class. You will need to keep in list format and work around the difficulties, or accept having NA values in the "extra rows".

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
n<-do.call(rbind,my_list<- lapply(1:10, function(i) matrix(data = runif(sample(seq(2,10,2), 1)), ncol = 2)))
myrow<-list(4,3,1,5,2,3,4,2)
mycol<-list(2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2)
myz<-as.list(rep(1,8))


my_array<-Map(function(x,y,z) array(n,c(x,y,z)), myrow, mycol,myz) # but this creates the list of 1 array
```